# Avoid feed_dict mechanism in static graph in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to implement a model for generating/reconstructing samples (Variational autoencoder). During test time, I would like to be able to make the model generate new samples by feeding it a latent variable, but that requires changing the inputs to a part of the computational graph.

I could use a feed_dict to "dynamically" do that, since I cannot directly change a static graph, but I want to avoid the overhead of exchanging data between the GPU and the system RAM.

As it stands I feed the data using Iterators.

```
def make_mnist_dataset(batch_size, shuffle=True, include_labels=True):
"""Loads the MNIST data set and returns the relevant
iterator along with its initialization operations.
"""

# load the data
train, test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# binarize and reshape the data sets
temp_train = train[0]
temp_train = (temp_train > 0.5).astype(np.float32).reshape(temp_train.shape[0], 784)
train = (temp_train, train[1])

temp_test = test[0]
temp_test = (temp_test > 0.5).astype(np.float32).reshape(temp_test.shape[0], 784)
test = (temp_test, test[1])

# prepare Dataset objects
if include_labels:
    train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    test_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test).repeat(1).batch(batch_size)
else:
    train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train[0]).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    test_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test[0]).repeat(1).batch(batch_size)

if shuffle:
    train_set = train_set.shuffle(buffer_size=int(0.5*train[0].shape[0]), 
                                  seed=123)

# make the iterator
iter = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_set.output_types,
                                       train_set.output_shapes)
data = iter.get_next()

# create initialization ops
train_init = iter.make_initializer(train_set)
test_init = iter.make_initializer(test_set)

return train_init, test_init, data
```

And here's the code snippet where the data being iterated over is being fed to the graph:

```
train_init, test_init, next_batch = make_mnist_dataset(batch_size, include_labels=True)
ops = build_graph(next_batch[0], next_batch[1], learning_rate, is_training, 
                  latent_dim, tau, batch_size, inf_layers, gen_layers)
```

Is there any way to "switch" from an Iterator object to a different input source during test time, without resorting to feed_dict?

Comment: You can use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to choose between different sources and you would only need to pass a boolean value through `feed_dict`. What exactly is it that you want to replace with what?

Comment: I did think about tf.cond(), but the problem is that the graph is built already with the Iterator in place. This is shown in the second snippet in the second line `ops = build_graph(next_batch[0], ...)`. At test time, I simply restore the same graph, I've found no way to feed a different input. I'm starting to think maybe subgraphing would solve the issue, I just wanted to know if there's a simpler way.

Comment: But do you have control over the parameters to `build_graph`? I meant using `tf.cond` before calling `build_graph`, not inside that function... Do you restore just the subgraph created with `build_graph`? In that case, maybe the [Graph Editor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/contrib.graph_editor) module can help?

Comment: The thing is that the static graph is already built with the Iterator defined as input. Symbolically, it does't matter where the Iterator is defined in the python code. If I try to define a new graph with a different input and restore the old one in its place as I naively tried to do I get errors. I do think, however, that Graph Editor might help!